# Apache LDAP Authentication with AD nested Subgroups

Tags: active-directory, apache-2.4, ldap

am trying to authenticate using an Active Directory User on a Apache with
nested Groups.

Apache 2.4.7
Ubuntu 14.4

I have a Group with Name `test` in this Group i have a few nested Groups
If i put the user in the test goup directly all fine. The user get authenticated. But if i put the user in a nested Group and put the nested Group in the Group `test` i get the errormessage.

didnt match with attr member [Comparison false (cached)] [5 - Compare false]

authoritation denied for user xyz

My Subgroupdepth is just one.

Anyone a idea ?

Best regards
mobios

My Config:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap users>
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=ldapbind,OU=Services,OU=Administration,DC=test,DC=tc"
AuthLDAPBindPassword Password
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://10.0.100.1:389/CN=Users,DC=test,DC=tc?sAMAccountName?sub"
</AuthnProviderAlias>


<AuthnProviderAlias ldap project>
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=ldapbind,OU=Services,OU=Administration,DC=test,DC=tc"
AuthLDAPBindPassword Password
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://10.0.100.1:389/OU=Projects,DC=test,DC=tc?sAMAccountName?sub"
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthzProviderAlias ldap-group test CN=test,CN=Users,,DC=test,DC=tc>
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=ldapbind,OU=Services,OU=Administration,DC=test,DC=tc"
AuthLDAPBindPassword Password
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://10.0.100.1:389/CN=Users,DC=test,DC=tc?sAMAccountName?sub"
</AuthzProviderAlias>

Alias /production /srv/webdav/production 
<Location "/production">
SSLRequireSSL 
DAV On 
Options None 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /dev/null 
AuthName "Repository production" 
AuthBasicProvider project users 
AuthLDAPMAxSubGroupDepth 10
AuthLDAPSubGroupAttribute member
AuthLDAPSubGroupClass Group
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
Require test
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
Order Deny,Allow 
</Location>
```

My active Directory Details are:

test.tc
|
|--(CN)Users--(CN)test
|
|--(OU)Projects--(OU)Group1--(CN)Group1

This are my Details in my active Directory.
(CN)test is the main Group and (CN)Group1
are nested in (CN)test.

Additionally i tried:
Require ldap-filter memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=test,CN=Users,dc=test,dc=tc

unfortunately dont work :(

Comment: Can you show the LDAP details of the 'test' group and the subgroup?

Comment: If i put the user directly to the Group test all is fine. If i put the group Group1 in the group test nothing works.